# Angular async pipe don't refreshes result after input array filtering

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

In a parent component I have a stream of Tour[] `tours_filtered: Observable<Tour[]>` which I assign in the subscribe function of an http request

```
this.api.getTours().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.tours_filtered = of(result.tours);
  }
)
```

in the view I display the stream using the async pipe

```
<app-tour-box [tour]="tour" *ngFor="let tour of tours_filtered | async"></app-tour-box>
```

Up to here all works as expected. In a child component I have an input text which emits the value inserted by the user to filtering the array of Tour by title.

In the parent component I listen for the emitted values in a function, I switch to new stream of Tour[] filtered by that value using switchMap

```
onSearchTitle(term: string) {
  this.tours_filtered.pipe(
    switchMap( 
      (tours) => of( tours.filter((tour) => tour.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)) )
    )
  )
}
```

I thought that the async pipe was constantly listening to reflect the changes to the array to which it was applied and so I thought I didn't have to subscribe in the function above, but nothing change in the view when I type in the input to filtering the results.

The results are updating correctly if I assign the new stream to the original array in the subscribe function

```
    onSearchTitle(term: string) {
        this.tours_filtered.pipe(
          switchMap((tours) => of(tours.filter((tour) => tour.name.toLowerCase().includes(term))))
        ).subscribe( val => { this.tours_filtered = of(val); })
      }
```

Is this procedure correct? Could I avoid to subscribe because I already use the async pipe? There is a better way to reach my goal?

EDITED:

Maybe I found a solution, I have to reassing a new stream to the variable just like this

```
onSearchTitle(term: string) {
    this.tours_filtered = of(this.city.tours).pipe(
      switchMap((tours) => of(tours.filter((tour) => tour.name.toLowerCase().includes(term))))
    );
  }
```

and I don't need to subscribe again, the results in the view change according to the search term typed by the user. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your situation the solution should work as follows:

```
onSearchTitle(term: string) {
  this._searchTerm = term;
  this.tours_filtered = of( 
    this.city.tours.filter((tour) => tour.name.toLowerCase().includes(term))
  )
}
```

Because in your example you don't change the observable which is used in `ngFor`. Thus it's not working.

However, I don't see the reason of using observables here unless this is the first step and you're going to fetch this data from server in future

---

**UPDATE**

The best solution for you would be to consider your input as an observable and watch for the changes:

```
// your.component.ts
export class AppComponent  {

  searchTerm$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  results = this.search(this.searchTerm$);

  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(term => {
          return of(this.city.tours.filter((tour) => tour.name.toLowerCase().includes(term)))
        }
        )
      )
  }

}
```

```
// your.template.html
...
<input type="" (input)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)">
...
```

Additionally it would be great to add `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged` for better user experience and less search requests.

See [full example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwkv3a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for the details. Also please, refer to [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/real-time-search-angular-rxjs/) for more detailed explanations

Comment: sorry my mistake, in the original version the swithMap operator was `switchMap((tours) => of(tours.filter((tour) => tour.name.toLowerCase().includes(term))))` but didn't work, I use observable to take advantage of the nature of switchMap which cancel the previous requests while user is typing the text to search

Comment: your solution is very nice if the input was in the same component with the other logic but it is in a child component in which I have collected all the possible filters to apply. I should create an `@Input()` property to pass in the tours array and the relative `@Output()` with the Observable<Tour[]> filtered or share a service between.

Comment: Please, provide a StackBlitz example with smth close to your example so I could fork it

Comment: Thanks, I solved sharing a service and now the source of observables are the controls in the child component , the parent only deals with displaying the results